# What's the term for a person who eats at a restaurant?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, formality

I'm not a native speaker and I'm trying to find a very specific term for a person who eats at a restaurant (from the owner's perspective).

In my native language, there's a word for *'client'* and another word that exclusively means *'person who eats at a restaurant.'* *'Customer'* and *'client'* came to mind, but they don't seem to fit, as they're broad terms (they can refer to multiple products / services, not just restaurants).

I already know of the term '*diner.'* But it may also refer to a location, not just a person.

Is there any other term I could use? I want the term to be very formal and I don't know if *'diner'* is formal / professional / clear enough.

Comment: Context should suffice for readers to understand your reference to *diner* indicates a human and not a restaurant.

Comment: [*Patron*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patron), perhaps?

Comment: Particularly in the UK, *diner* refers far more to the person.

Comment: @Mick Patron as in 'le patron' is almost always used to refer to the boss or the chef-patron in a French restaurant in France or in a French restaurant overseas. But this does not stop native English speakers (particularly in UK) from using the word 'patronize' as in, Fred Bloggs is a good customer; he has patronized our restaurant ever since it opened 3-years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another common term is "guest".

"Customer" would be appropriate as would be "diner", but "client" would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**consumer**   is also used, for ex, "Soup is served to stimulate the **consumers’** appetite."